# Google APIs Key

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I am using Google maps and generated a key for debug. I have heard that with the API v3 the key is no longer needed. Is this correct? Can I work without a key for release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will *always* need an API-key to download the tile-maps and map-engine v3. Please take a look at the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:1010634796015) from google.

Comment: for some reason I don't have access to this project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use only debug key for Google maps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What are the steps I need to perform in order to use Google maps without a key?

Comment: You will need a key. Either of this Debug or release one. For development purpose you just need debug key.